# Difference between the two?

Tags: c++

I just started C++, and I was wondering. What is the difference between the two Operator functions? I know the first one is an array, but what does the % in the second one mean?

```
T operator[] (int k) const {
    return 0;
}

T operator% () (int k) const {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They both seem pretty useless. These are user-defined `operator`s. They can do whatever you tell them to do. In this case, both ignore their argument and `return` 0. The only difference is the name.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: There are many more operators that can be overloaded.

Comment: `T operator% () (int k) const` means "compile error". Are you trying to overload `operator%` or `operator()`?

Comment: @boboobobo : If you think that the question should make some sense, please consider editing and clarify whether the the code is inside a printed example you saw somewhere. I have never seen such a construct never before and as Ferdinand  has suggested, it would result in a compile time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An operator is a function which can be represented with a special syntax. So the following, if defined on a class MyClass:

```
T MyClass::operator% (int k);
```

can be called as follows:

```
MyClass a;
int k = 1;
T answer = a % k;
```

The other operator:

```
T MyClass::operator[] (int k);
```

Can be called by:

```
T answer = a[k];
```

By convention the % operator is called the modulo operator, while the [] operator is called the subscript operator, but you as they are just functions you can redefine them to make them do what you like.

Comment: Why didn't you point out that his attempt to overload the second operator, ie %, will result in a compile time error as he had put a () after % making the compiler confused.

Comment: That's a good point, I missed that in answering the more general question.

Comment: In fact he might have understood the general concept and may be confused by a wrong example.. so please explain the answer further to specifically address his question

Answer (score 0):

They both just mean operators, in fact '[]' does not mean array, it mean whatever you may want it to be (although is usually used for indexin over objects or array initializations).

Check [operators overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) for more information about this topic. But making a resume, almost any common operator can be redefined for custom behaviour on specific objects or data.